# Run a command given its name as a string

Tags: macros

Is there a way to define a command like `\escape` such that it can run a command with a given name? So, for example, `\escape{foo}` will execute the command `\foo`, possibly with arguments.

Comment: @campa What about for getting the source code of a command?

Comment: You can simply use `\verbatim` for that, or if you want to write a documentation or simply escape the backslash itself: `\\foo`

Comment: @Someone you can show the definition of a macro on the terminal by using `\show`: `\show\macro`. If you want to print it in your document, you can use `\meaning`: `\texttt{\meaning\macro}`. If you want to print `\newcommand` to your document, you can use `\usepackage{etoolbox}\makeatletter\newrobustcmd\escape[1]{\texttt{\@backslashcar#1}}\makeatother`. If you want the macro to be expanded, after using `\usepackage{etoolbox}` you can then use `\csuse` (like `\csuse{newcommand}`).

Comment: There is also \@namedef{hi}{hi}.

Comment: @DG': I think they’re not asking to *typeset* the name of the command (as `\verbatim` or `\\foo` would do) but to have the macro actually be expanded as `\foo` itself, and then further processed however `\foo` itself would be. See their example with `\newcommand`, for instance.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine - You are probably right, but the question is not very clear and maybe the OP just wanted a simple solution, before trying complicated things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just want `\@namueuse`.

- `\@nameuse{foo}` becomes `\foo`
- `{\@nameuse{newcommand}}{\hi}{hi}` really means `{\newcommand}{\hi}{hi}`, which is an error. But I think it is just an error in the question, and you intended  `\escape{newcommand}{\hi}{hi}` (without some braces).

Use

```
\makeatletter
\let\escape=\@nameuse
\makeatother
```

Or skip right into the simple definition of `\@nameuse`

```
\newcommand*\escape[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
```

Comment: Shows how nooby I am at LaTeX. However, how do `\csname` and `\endcsname` work?

Comment: @Someone Stuff between `\csname..\endcsname` is expanded and is expected to yield character tokens that denote the name of a control sequence token. That control sequence token is delivered. In case it is not yet defined at the time of carrying out `\csname..\endcsname` it will within the current scope/group be let equal to the `\relax`-primitive. E.g., `\csname foobar\endcsname` yields the control sequence token `\foobar`. With `\def\foo{foobar}` `\csname\foo\endcsname` also yields the control sequence token `\foobar`. If `\foobar` was undefined it will be as if you said `\let\foobar=\relax`.

Comment: @Someone If you don't want to use LaTeX for just one project, which is imposed on you by someone who wants to be "hip", but plan to use LaTeX a lot, so that it's worth learning all that stuff, then I suggest you ask questions and hereby explain what you mean how things work and fit together. This is a fast way to get rid of misunderstandings related to how TeX/LaTeX works. It can be very useful to have conversation with responders. StackExchange is not really intended to be a conversation medium. In the past I got a lot of explanation and teaching in the usenet newsgroup comp.text.tex.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken`:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

*(If this suits your needs you can replace `\CsNameToCsToken` by `\escape`. But I think the name "CsNameToCsToken" does better describe what the macro in question does.)*

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

Definition (in LaTeX 2ε):

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
    \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\z@#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
}%
```

In plain-TeX

- either also define `\z@`, e.g., to be a macro which expands to `0⟨explicit space token⟩`, or to be a `\dimendef`-token denoting a register holding length-value 0pt,
- or do:

  ```
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral0\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
  \long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}% <- the space before #1 must be!
  }%
  \long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
  ```

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

---

And here is the requested `\NewDocumentCommand`-example:

With `\NewDocumentCommand` you don't really need braces surrounding the control sequence token to define.

E.g.,
`\NewDocumentCommand\foo{m}{foo's argument is: #1}`
is the same as
`\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{foo's argument is: #1}`

Therefore you can do:

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo...`  .

---

You can as well use such a macro for defining/calling macros whose names contain spaces:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo }` → `\foo␣`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo }` → `\newcommand\foo␣`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo }` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo␣`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo }` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo␣`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo }\bar` → `\expandafter\foo␣\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo }=\bar` → `\let\foo␣=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo }` → `\string\foo␣`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo }` → `\meaning\foo␣`  .

You can also nest the calls of `\CsNameToCsToken`:

**Example 1:**

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{f o o }{b a r }`

Processing the first `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣{b a r }`  .

Processing the second `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\b␣a␣r␣`  .

(Analogously: `\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{f o o }={b a r }` → `\let\f␣o␣o␣=\b␣a␣r␣`.)

**Example 2:**

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

Processing the first `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the second `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the third `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

**Example 3:**

In expansion contexts you can use `\romannumeral`-expansion in order to keep things going.

`\romannumeral\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\z@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

`\romannumeral` triggers expansion until TeX has found a sequence of tokens that forms a *⟨number⟩*-quantity. In the end TeX will find the *⟨number⟩*-quantity `\z@` whose value is `0` while with non-positive numbers `\romannumeral` silently swallows the tokens forming the *⟨number⟩*-quantity while not delivering any token at all:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\z@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{f o o }\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`

Processing the first `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\z@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter{b a r }{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the second `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\CsNameToCsToken\z@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣{c r a z y }`  .

Processing the third `\CsNameToCsToken` yields:
   `%\romannumneral-expansion in progress`
   `\z@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

Now `\romannumeral` finds `\z@`, i.e., the number `0` (in a way where no further digits and no to be discarded space-token terminating the *⟨number⟩* will be searched). Therefore `\romannumeral`-expansion gets aborted and `\romannumeral` won't deliver any token:
   `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\f␣o␣o␣\expandafter\b␣a␣r␣\c␣r␣a␣z␣y␣`  .

Be aware that `\CsNameToCsToken` internally applies `\csname` while applying `\csname` as a side effect yields assigning the control sequence in question the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive in case the control sequence in question was undefined before applying `\csname`. That assignment will be restricted to the current scope even if the `\globaldefs`-parameter had a positive value at the time of applying `\csname`.

Comment: That's a lot of complicated stuff. Could you show an example with `\NewDocumentCommand` instead? Thank you.

This still deserves an upvote, though!

Comment: @Someone  Done. ;-)